# unobtrusive validation not triggering when using submit() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

In my view I have a button that submits the form:

`<input type="button" value="Save Only" id="save" onclick="submitForm('SaveOnly')" />`

This is one of a few different buttons, all of which will be handled differently in different Controller Action methods.

Also in the view is this `submitForm(action)` Javascript method:

```
function submitForm(action) {
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    form.action = "/Area/MyController/" + action;
    form.submit();
}
```

When I use a `submit` button (rather than `type="button"`), unobtrusive client-side validation works properly. However, when I use this `submitForm(action)` function, the client-side validation does not happen. How can trigger the client side validation?

Comment: Are any errors showing up in the console?

Comment: No. Also the server side validation is working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can call it manually as follows:

```
function submitForm(action) {
    var $form = $("#myForm");
    $form.action = "/Area/MyController/" + action;

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
    $form.validate();

    if ($form.valid()) {
       $form.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a console error: `form.validate is not a function`

Comment: @navig8tr I have changed it to use a jQuery selector now instead, please re-try the code above. :)

Comment: different console error: `Cannot read property 'form' of undefined`

Comment: Correct the selector to `var $form = $("#myForm");`

Comment: Perfect! Now I can go home happy. :-)

Comment: Btw, this already shows the validation messages without adding the`$.each` block.