# How to trigger ASP .NET Core MVC client-side validation without submitting

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

How do you trigger client-side validation in ASP .NET Core MVC without submitting a form?

I am using modals, and need to trigger validation (without submitting the form).

In jQuery, I could do this

```
$('#formID').validate().form()
```

However, I would like to trigger the unobtrusive validation included in ASP .NET Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can use this code:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ClassicMovie(1960)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 999.99)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    public bool Preorder { get; set; }
}
```

Please check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Just to clarify, I already have data annotations and everything works when I submit the form.  However, I want to trigger an unobtrusive validation without having to submit the form.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225968/unobtrusive-validation-not-triggering-when-using-submit-function

Comment: Perfect that worked!  `var form = $('#formID');
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
     var validate =   form.validate().form();`

Answer (score 4):

Unobtrusive validation still exists with ASP.NET Core, you just have to include the relevant scripts. Here's a full example.

Assuming this model:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this controller action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new SomeViewModel());
}
```

And finally, the view:

```
@model SomeViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<form asp-action="Index" id="formID" method="post">
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Silly example to demonstrate.
            $('#formID').validate().form();

            if ($('#formID').valid() === false) {
                console.log("invalid");
            } else {
                console.log("valid!");
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

If you take a look inside `~/Views/Shared/_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`, you'll see it contains:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

If you look in your developer tools console, it should validate the form immediately as the page is loaded, and display the required field is missing validation message next to the `Name` textbox.

Comment: Essentially, nobody wants their validation to fire as soon as the page gets loaded, its better to fire it when the form is submitted i.e `$('body').on('submit','#formID',function() {})` event